# Visualising JSON Strings stored in a .json file

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a lot of JSON strings stored in a .json file. I find it helpful to use the browser parsing the JSON string and showing it in a well manner.
Well, that's correct for a well formatted structure.

But when I have multiple strings like this:

```
{"data":"value"}

{"data":"value"}

{"data":"value"}
```

It gives error.

What it needs to generate proper HTML is:

```
[

{"data":"value"},

{"data":"value"},

{"data":"value"},

]
```

How do I achieve this without altering the .json file?

Now, before parsing, I can concatenate [ at the start and ] at the end.But, how do I separate the {} {} {} strings with a "," so that I can parse that file easily.

[This might sound confusing, Refer the picture..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxLTV.png)

Comment: Huh? _generate proper HTML_? Show us what you tried, you need to make sure the json is valid, that's all - If you have the data as you described, than it's an invalid json

Comment: @AlonEitan I have attached the picture which shall explain what issue I have. Please let me know if need more!

Comment: Can Anyone please help me get through this?

Answer (score 0):

This was done using SED and AWK.
Using SED, I could insert `,` where `}{` occurred (replace `}{` with `},{` ) and finally using AWK I could put complete string into `[]` then it became readable for the Browser(my case firefox).

Previous:

```
{"data":"value"}{"data":"value"}
```

Now:

```
[{"data":"value"},{"data":"value"}]
```

Now it shows all the JSON data parsed in a easily readable way.

Thanks to my PhD colleague though! Happy to share :)